# NSProgressIndicator in NSMenuItem not updating on second display

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit, nsrunloop, nsprogressindicator

I've got a `NSMenu` attached to a `NSStatusItem` (a menu bar application). While downloading a file I want to display a NSProgressIndicator in an item of this menu. I've created a `NSViewController` subclass for this progress indicator with the following properties:

```
@property NSUInteger current; // Bound to NSProgressIndicator value
@property NSString *status;   // Bound to a NSTextField value
@property NSUInteger total;   // Bound to NSProgressIndicator max value
```

When needed I start the download of the file with the following code, which runs in `NSRunLoopCommonModes` so that the delegate methods are also called when the `NSMenu` is displayed (which runs in `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode`):

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
[connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[connection start];
```

In the `didReceiveData` delegate method I then set the properties on my `NSViewController` subclass:

```
progressViewController.current = receivedData.length;
progressViewController.status = @"Downloading...";
progressViewController.total = expectedBytes;
```

This works great if I bind the properties to a label, but the `NSProgressIndicator` only updates if I open the menu **before** the connection is started, and don't close it again until the download is finished. But if I open it afterwards, the progress indicator doesn't update. It shows the value the properties had at the moment I opened the menu, but this value doesn't update. The progress indicator then isn't animated either. Note that labels **do** work...

I tried to manually call `setNeedsDisplay` with `YES` and call `display` om on both the custom view and the progress indicator when I change the values, but that doesn't work. The only thing that does fix the progress indicator is calling `[progress setHidden:YES]; [progress setHidden:NO];` in rapid succession, but that causes the progress indicator to flicker, and is of course a bad solution.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this `NSProgressIndicator`?

Comment: Hi Frog, I'm facing a similar problem. I have a NSProgressIndicator inside a NSMenuItem. It is animating when I open it the first time but not the second time. Did you find any solution to your problem?

Comment: I was never able to solve this exact problem, but the bug doesn't occur when you place the `NSProgressIndicator` in a `NSTableView`. Because I needed a list of indicators anyways, doing that was no problem for me. I still don't know how to fix this exact problem though... Could be another bug with a view in a `NSMenuItem`...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this answer solved my problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4692194/406677

In swift:

```
progressIndicator.performSelector("startAnimation:", withObject:self, afterDelay: 0.0, inModes: [NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode])
```